# Rails Encoding UTF-8 error in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, utf-8

i have this collection select with a :prompt attribute

```
<%= collection_select(:man_id, :name, Manufactor.where(:indropdown => true), :name, :name, {:prompt => "#{'Любой'.force_encoding('utf-8')}"}) %>
```

I cannot get the prompt to display the russian word. The error in this:

> ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):

Any Help on this encoding issue?

Using rails 3.0.5

Comment: solved by using Numerical Code and html_safe

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own questions and accept those answers, that's even encouraged if you think someone else might have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issues by using Numerical Code and html_safe

This solved the problem for me but still the issue remains if i need to write russian letters in my application.